# check if a string only contains specific characters?

Tags: python, string, validation, passwords, character

I need to check a string (password validator) whether it contains specific characters and lenght **in python**. One of the condition is, that the string ***pwd*** **only contains the characters** **a-z, A-Z, digits, or the special chars "+", "-", "*", "/".**

> Blockquote

These utilities should help me solve it (but I don't get it):

- Use *isupper/islower* to decide whether a string is upper case or lower
  case
- Use *isdigit* to check if it is a number
- Use the *in* operator to check whether a specific character exists in a
  string.

```
pwd = "abc"

def is_valid():
    # You need to change the following part of the function
    # to determine if it is a valid password.
    validity = True

    # You don't need to change the following line.
    return validity

# The following line calls the function and prints the return
# value to the Console. This way you can check what it does.
print(is_valid())
```

I'd appreciate your help!

Comment: I suggest you look in the internet about "regular expressions" or regex

Answer (score 0):

We can use `re.search` here for a regex option:

```py
def is_valid(pwd):
    return re.search(r'^[A-Za-z0-9*/+-]+$', pwd) is not None

print(is_valid("abc"))   # True
print(is_valid("ab#c"))  # False
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regex, but as the task only involves checking that characters belong to a **set**, it might be more efficient to just use **python sets**:

```
def is_valid(pwd):
    from string import ascii_letters
    chars = set(ascii_letters+'0123456789'+'*-+/')
    return all(c in chars for c in pwd)
```

examples:

```
>>> is_valid('abg56*-+')
True

>>> is_valid('abg 56*')
False
```

##### Alternative using a regex:

```
def is_valid(pwd):
    import re
    return bool(re.match(r'[a-zA-Z\d*+-/]*$', pwd))
```

Comment: Also, you can check the length right in the regex. For example, you want at least 8 characters: `return bool(re.fullmatch(r'[a-zA-Z\d*+-/]{8,}', pwd))` . That's the whole function, one line with regex :)

Comment: @Expurple sure regex are nice when more constraints apply, I had not seen the length constraint in question ;)

Comment: My other comment can't be edited anymore :( I've just noticed that our character class has a bug. `+-/` will be interpreted as a range. Need to escape the `-`. That's why it's better to always double check every pattern on [regexr.com](https://regexr.com) or similar